# Spring @Cacheable @CacheEvict and @Transactional race condition

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, transactions, race-condition

I am using `@Cacheable`, `@CacheEvict`, and `@Transactional` in a typical multi-threaded application but am facing a race condition that I don't know of a good way to resolve it. The only working solution I have now is not to use cache at all, but that is not desirable. Want to see if the SO community can have a better solution. Here is an example setup:

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = CACHE_NAME)
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, String> {
    @Cacheable
    MyTable getMyTable(String id);
    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
    MyTable saveMyTable(MyTable myTable);
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    @Transactional
    public MyTable createMyTable(String id) {
        return myRepo.saveMyTable(new MyTable(id));
    }
}

public void method(String id) {
    MyTable t = myRepo.getMyTable(id); //...1
    if (t == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            t = myRepo.getMyTable(id); //...2
            if (t == null) {
                t = myService.createMyTable(id); //...3
            }
        }
    }
    // do work on t
}
```

So the goal is to cache the get value using id as the key and then evict all the cached values (i.e. all the ids) when a new value is saved.

The race condition happens when a thread (T1) is in the middle of `3`, where the cache has been evicted but before the change commits to the database, during this moment another thread (T2) calls `1`, it will get a miss in the cache, then it checks from the database, surely database would return null and null is cached for that id.

As T1 commits and exits the synchronized block, T2 does the second check again at `2`, normally without caching, this would tell T2 that there is an entry of that id in the database already and no action needs to be done, however, due to the race condition above, the cached null value returns without actually checking the database and T2 continues to create a new entry with the same id, throwing exception.

Potentially, I think if the cache eviction and transaction commit are done atomically, it should be bug free, but not sure how `@CacheEvict` and `@Transactional` can be made depending on each other. Thank you.